# light at maximum normal?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I just got a 6th generation Kindle paperwhite and I have to have the light up to the maximum to get a decent light to read it during the daytime indoors.  Is this normal?  Why would it not have a stronger light that I could dim if I wanted to?  My older version of Kindle paperwhite (that I lost) had the light more in the middle to upper middle to get the strength of this one at max.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for a replacement.  Generally, a brightness setting of 9 is quite enough for day/night reading.  Actually, 9 is still too bright in the dark.

This happens with most of the Kindles since they are mass-produced in China and don't follow the lumens standard, nor was it written anywhere in the description, so that we can verify it.  I have seen the Kindle white is white but the Kindle black appears slightly yellowish to me.